# Django left join models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to left join the below tables and add a filter condition on approved_coupon field.

My models

```
class Voucher(models.Model):
    voucher_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    voucher_code = models.CharField()

class ApprovedCouponLine(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    approved_coupon = models.ForeignKey(ApprovedCoupon, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='approved_coupon_lines')
    coupon_code = models.ForeignKey(Voucher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='approved_coupon_lines_coupons')
```

I tried this, but it shows the inner join.

```
queryset = Voucher.objects.filter(approved_coupon_lines_coupons__approved_coupon_id='CD5FC4FE').values_list('code', flat=True)
```

Current Query:

```
SELECT "voucher_voucher"."code", "voucher_approvedcouponline"."id"  
FROM "voucher_voucher" 
INNER JOIN "voucher_approvedcouponline" ON ("voucher_voucher"."id" = "voucher_approvedcouponline"."coupon_code_id") 
WHERE "voucher_approvedcouponline"."approved_coupon_id" = 'CD5FC4FE'
```

Expected Query:

```
SELECT "voucher_voucher"."code", "voucher_approvedcouponline"."id" 
FROM "voucher_voucher" 
LEFT JOIN "voucher_approvedcouponline" ON ("voucher_voucher"."id" = "voucher_approvedcouponline"."coupon_code_id" AND 
                                            "voucher_approvedcouponline"."approved_coupon_id" = 'CD5FC4FE'
                                      )
```

What I missed in the above example?